# YAML syntax for HTML span and underscore character

Tags: html, string, yaml, escaping, r-markdown

I'm using R, blowdown and Hugo to build a html site.
There is text specified in the .yml file which should have a single underscore at the end like `header1_`. The line should be in color, while the text is black.

In the YAML the text is specified as

```
title: "header1<span style=\"color:#ff5740\">_</span>"
```

In the corresponding html file the title is set using:

```
<h1 style="color:white">{{ .title | markdownify }}</h1>
```

This works very well

[image]

Now I want a second new line with the same style. Thus, I wrote in the YAML:

```
title: "header1<span style=\"color:#ff5740\">_</span><br>header2<span style=\"color:#ff5740\">_</span>"
```

Here the `_` makes the second header italic...as expected in markdown.

[image]

Of course I can escape the line. But `\_` or `\__` are not working.The line don't show up or is separated by a space from the text. And using ```` changes the style somehow...the underscore is bold and the color ist different (compare it to the box at the bottom & figure 1).

[image: ![enter image description here]

Any ideas?

Comment: Should the line really be a text? If not, then create it completely in CSS, in this case no adjustments to the title would be necessary.

Comment: … or use `&lowbar;`

Comment: Hehe, ok...this was easy! :) Thanks.